# Unable to capture process id from $! in bash 3.2.57

Tags: bash

On my remote server with bash 4.2.46, I can do this:

```
$ sleep 100 & pid=$!; echo "$pid"; wait "$pid"
[3] 7646
7646
```

However, on my Mac with bash 3.2.57, it does not work:

```
$ sleep 100 & pid=$!; echo "$pid"; wait "$pid"
-bash: !: event not found
```

What is going on? Somehow I have been using macOS `bash` for years without ever running into this problem before... but I swear I have run plenty of shell programs that do this exact `$!` method to grab the process id of a background process and never had it break.

Comment: Does `echo "${!}"` work any better? If you only have one bg job, or can match the command, you could capture the pid from `jobs -l`

Comment: yes `sleep 100 & pid=${!};` also appears to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `!` is the trigger character for [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html), enabled in interactive shells by default.

I don't think it would do anything useful in `pid=$!;` like in your case, or in `echo "$!"`. As you can see from the error message, it tries to use an empty string to search for, as opposed to something like `!foo` looking for `foo`. Newer versions of Bash are more sensible in that `$!` or `"!"` don't trigger it, but 3.2 is a bit stupid with that.

What seems to work is `pid=$! ;`, with the space before the semicolon. Or you could just disable history expansion with `set +H`. (Note that `"$!"` *doesn't* work in 3.2.)

Comment: the space before the semicolon does indeed fix it. I had no clue that it was required in this case. I've admittedly never been consistent in my usage of that, some scripts I put the space and others I don't. I guess I just got lucky every time all these years wow

Comment: @user5359531, in scripts it shouldn't even come up, since history expansion is disabled in that case. It's only a problem if you type a command like that on an interactive shell's prompt. The behaviour on 3.2 is somewhat painful, so I'm not surprised it's been changed. Though personally, I just turned history expansion off for good, with all the quirks it has, it's more of a nuisance than it's useful. (or maybe I just haven't bothered to learn how to use it.)